# RestKit .22: Unable to successfully map relationship with nested JSON

Tags: ios, rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've been wrestling with relationship mapping with RestKit for days now. I can get a single object fine, but nested JSON data arrays are not getting mapped and looking at the trace logs I can't find any errors. As much as it hurts, I admit it has gotten the best of me. I've looked through as many examples as I could and tried different solutions based on what other people were doing in their situations but nothing's working. I tried to follow the RKGist example that accompanies the RestKit documentation, but unfortunately the section on relationship mapping hasn't been written yet, there are only placeholders there.

This is the JSON example response I'm working with:

```
{
"stat": {
    "code": 200
},
"data": {
    "channel": {
        "_id": "68413dzz39f4843t8500000d",
        "desc": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "owner": {
            "_id": "584ege8239f4883f6200000b",
            "name": "..."
        },
        "count": {
            "invited": 0,
            "joined": 1,
            "subscribers": 0,
            "posts": 0,
            "messages": 0
        },
        "access": "PUB"
    },
    "affiliation": "...",
    "member_statuses": [
        {
            "channel": {
                "_id": "68413dzz39f4843t8500000d",
                "name": "..."
            },
            "owner": {
                "_id": "584ege8239f4883f6200000b",
                "dname": "...",
                "name": "..."
            },
            "type": "...",
            "message": "This is the message text",
            "_id": "52222e3039f4884tkk00000e",
            "taken": "2013-11-11T20:23:45.938Z",
            "access": "PUB"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I'm unable to post images yet, as this is the first question I've not been able to find an answer for. But the two relevant Core Data models and NSManagedObject subclasses are:

`THChannel.h`

I've set up a relationship called `posts` with a destination of `THPost` with an inverse of `post`. I selected the type as `To Many` as multiple posts can belong to one channel

```
@class THPost, THUser;

@interface THChannel : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * accessCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * channelId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countComments;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countInvited;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countJoined;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countMessages;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countPhotos;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countPosts;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * countSubscribers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * createdAt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * desc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) THUser *owner;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *posts;
@end

@interface THChannel (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addPostsObject:(THPost *)value;
- (void)removePostsObject:(THPost *)value;
- (void)addPosts:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removePosts:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

`THPost.h`

I've set up a relationship called `post` with a destination of `THChannel` with an inverse of `posts`. I selected the type as `To One` as multiple posts can belong to one channel

```
@class THChannel, THUser;

@interface THPost : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * postId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * channelId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ownerTypeCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ownerId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * postTypeCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * messageText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * createdAt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * takenAt;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * accessTypeCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) THChannel *post;
@property (nonatomic, retain) THUser *owner;

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
// Log all HTTP traffic with request and response bodies
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

// Log debugging info about Core Data
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/CoreData", RKLogLevelDebug);
RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);

NSError *error = nil;

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:API_BASE_URL];
NSIndexSet *successStatusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx status codes

[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager].enabled = YES;

RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// Initialize managed object store
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *path = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
NSDictionary *options = @{  NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @(NO),
                            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @(NO) };
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:path fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:options error:&error];
if (! persistentStore) {
    RKLogError(@"Failed adding persistent store at path '%@': %@", path, error);
}

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

RKEntityMapping *channelEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"THChannel" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

channelEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"channelId" ];
[channelEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"_id": @"channelId",
                                                            @"name": @"name",
                                                            @"desc": @"desc",
                                                            @"access": @"accessCode",
                                                            @"nmupl": @"nonMemberUploads",
                                                            @"meta.created": @"createdAt",
                                                            @"affiliation": @"viewerAffiliationCode",
                                                            @"canPost": @"viewerCanPost",
                                                            @"count.subscribers": @"countSubscribers",
                                                            @"count.comments": @"countComments",
                                                            @"count.posts": @"countPosts",
                                                            @"count.photos": @"countPhotos",
                                                            @"count.messages": @"countMessages",
                                                            @"count.joined": @"countJoined",
                                                            @"count.invited": @"countInvited" }];

RKEntityMapping *postEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"THPost" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

postEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"postId" ];
[postEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"_id": @"postId",
                                                         @"channel._id": @"channelId",
                                                         @"type": @"postTypeCode",
                                                         @"message": @"messageText",
                                                         @"meta.created": @"createdAt",
                                                         @"taken": @"takenAt",
                                                         @"access": @"accessTypeCode"
                                                         }];




[channelEntityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"member_statuses" toKeyPath:@"posts" withMapping:postEntityMapping]];

NSEntityDescription *postEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"THPost" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
 NSRelationshipDescription *postRelationship = [postEntity relationshipsByName][@"post"];
 RKConnectionDescription *connection2 = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:postRelationship attributes:@{ @"channelId": @"channelId" }];
 [postEntityMapping addConnection:connection2];

RKResponseDescriptor *channelsOverviewObjectDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:channelEntityMapping
                                                                                              method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                         pathPattern:@"/channels/:channelID"
                                                                                             keyPath:@"data.channel"
                                                                                         statusCodes:successStatusCodes];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[channelsOverviewObjectDescriptor]];

// Set the default store shared instance
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:manager];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that:

```
[channelEntityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"member_statuses" toKeyPath:@"posts" withMapping:postEntityMapping]];
```

is for nested data and that isn't what you have. You have 2 different dictionaries with 2 different types of data.

Fortunately, the `member_statuses` array contains the `id`s of the associated channels so you can perform a foreign key mapping. You are also already mapping the channel id into the post (this is the other required part). For this you will need 2 response descriptors that operate on the same response. 1 for the channels and one for the posts. It is the post mapping that should make the connection to the channels (so remove the property mapping from the channel mapping).

The foreign key mapping should be setup something like:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"THPost" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
NSRelationshipDescription *relationship = [entity relationshipsByName][@"post"];
RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:e
```

relationship attributes:@{ @"channelId": @"channelId" }];

And then add the connection to the post mapping.

Comment: Wain, one day in the future you're going to look back and wonder if you made a difference in this lifetime. I will go ahead and tell you yes, yes you did. You saved my sanity. 

You hit the nail on the head with the additional response descriptor that I needed. The connection between both entities were being made, but the posts were not being picked up and saved because of the missing response descriptor. After your explanation it makes sense why that data wasn't treated as nested data, but that was hard to see with everything going on. 

I appreciate you taking the time to answer. Thanks!